# [Google App Engine]Return None when I crop image with image API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Have a nice day.

In my dev environment, I tried to crop a image which was stored on google cloud storage and we can access and show that image with below URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/img/encoded_gs_file:YXBwX2RlZmF1bHRfYnVja2V0LzIwMTUvNy8yMy90aG9kYW4uanBn
with "encoded_gs_file:YXBwX2RlZmF1bHRfYnVja2V0LzIwMTUvNy8yMy90aG9kYW4uanBn" is the blob_key of blob where the image is stored.

I used

```
class google.appengine.api.images.Image(image_data=None, blob_key=None, filename=None)[source]
```

in this GAE API link:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images

And this is my code to crop that image:

```
    import google.appengine.api.images as _gimage


    blob_key = 'encoded_gs_file:YXBwX2RlZmF1bHRfYnVja2V0LzIwMTUvNy8yMy90aG9kYW4uanBn'
    img = _gimage.Image(blob_key=blob_key)
    logger.debug('BLOB KEY: %s' % blob_key)

    left = 0.0
    top= 0.0
    right = 0.3
    bottom = 0.3
    cropped_img = img.crop(left_x=left, top_y=top, right_x=width, bottom_y=height)
    #img.resize(width=80, height=100)
    logger.debug('CROPPED IMAGE: %r' % cropped_img)
```

however, "cropped_img" return None object, it means this crop is really fail. The logs are showed below:

```
2015-07-23 07:19:43,683:DEBUG:BLOB KEY: encoded_gs_file:YXBwX2RlZmF1bHRfYnVja2V0LzIwMTUvNy8yMy90aG9kYW4uanBn
2015-07-23 07:19:43,684:DEBUG:Handled logservice.Flush in 0.0002
2015-07-23 07:19:43,689:DEBUG:Handled images.GetUrlBase in 0.0031
2015-07-23 07:19:43,691:DEBUG:Handled logservice.Flush in 0.0003
2015-07-23 07:19:43,692:DEBUG:<google.appengine.api.images.Image object at 0x7f1eac1873d0>
2015-07-23 07:19:43,694:DEBUG:Handled logservice.Flush in 0.0004
2015-07-23 07:19:43,694:DEBUG:CROPPED IMAGE: None
```

And I cannot find out the root cause of this issue. Could you guys please help me to explain and fix this error? Thank you very very much in advance.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Why are you assuming that `None` means `crop` failed? I am not seeing anything returned in the soruces of `crop`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images#Image.crop so I'd think this is expected.

Comment: Hi Russu, thank you very much for your help. I re-sized this image and it is ok. So, I think that the crop process was fail when it returned None object although I did the steps as in the guide. I read the link that you provided me and I am so sorry when I cannot change the result. Have you cropped any image yet? Please help me if you know anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @MihailRussu, you can not seeing anything when you run my code because you have to save an image to Google cloud storage before and you will get a blob  key. About this key: 'encoded_gs_file:YXBwX2RlZmF1bHRfYnVja2V0LzIwMTUvNy8yMy90aG9kYW4uanBn' is my blob key that was taken for examples. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MihailRussu, I fixed this error. As you asked me, I cannot sure that 'None" was returned means the cropped process is fail. The root cause of this issue is GAE will crop that image directly, so we no need to  use: "cropped_img = img.crop(left_x=left, top_y=top, right_x=width, bottom_y=height)" and just need: img.crop(left_x=left, top_y=top, right_x=width, bottom_y=height). Thank you very much again.